# PHP download / stream file to browser - max execution timeout error

Tags: php, download, file-read

Situation: we store files on Amazon S3 and write the infos into our database. Now the user can download the files by a download link like www.myserver.de/downloadFile?id=1234

This works quite well, but we get several "Maximum execution time of 800 seconds exceeded" errors.

Our current code for the download:

```
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: -1");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    if($mimeType)
    {
        header("Content-Type: ".$mimeType);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.";");
    }

    header("Content-length: ".$filesize);

    $s3Client = new s3Client();
    //download the file from s3 to local server
    $s3Client->getFile($folder, $filename, $tempFolder.$filename);

    $filehandle = fopen($tempFolder.$filename, "rb");
    while(!feof($filehandle))
    {
        print(@fread($filehandle, 1024*8));
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if(connection_status() != 0)
        {
            @fclose($filehandle);
            unlink($tempFolder.$filename);
            exit;
        }
    }

    @fclose($filehandle);
    unlink($tempFolder.$filename);
    exit;
```

The max execution time error happens even with very small files (just some KB). It looks like there is a problem in while loop and it wont be terminated?

The strange thing is: the download works anyway?

When we get the timeout error in our log, we try the download ourselves and it works perfectly.

The source for this way of downloading files is: http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Comment: maybe you need do that in background store the progress in a database

Comment: One question for clarity... If say a user doesn't use this php script, can **anyone** go and download the file? (that is: can they go to the link and download it in the browser?)

Comment: the download script is the only way, there is no direct link to the file because of permissions.